# Less Framework > Does CSS load in everything first and then select?

Tags: css, frameworks, less

When using the less framework, does CSS only load what is relevant to the device or does it load the entire CSS and then pick what's needed?

I want to use a nice background for the Desktop version, but for iPhones, iPads etc, I want a stripped down version to show up.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: Do you mean LESSCSS (Variables, Mixins, .less format), or the LESS framework (http://lessframework.com)? If it's the latter refer to http://lessframework.com/#how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less generates a CSS file which is then picked by your HTML file. There is no other rocket science involved.

If you want to have different variations of your website for different devices you need to detect the device first and then use desired stylesheet (which could be a different CSS file).

Google is your friend: http://iphone.wikidot.com/detection

Comment: Thanks bzx! I'll probably use that technique then.